# How to mimic a command line run with arguements inside a PHP script?

Tags: php, shell, command-line

How can you mimic a command line run of a script with arguements inside a PHP script?  Or is that not possible?

In other words, let's say you have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
require "../src/php/whatsprot.class.php";

function fgets_u($pStdn) {
    $pArr = array($pStdn);

    if (false === ($num_changed_streams = stream_select($pArr, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, 0))) {
        print("\$ 001 Socket Error : UNABLE TO WATCH STDIN.\n");
        return FALSE;
    } elseif ($num_changed_streams > 0) {
        return trim(fgets($pStdn, 1024));
    }
}

$nickname = "WhatsAPI Test";
$sender =   ""; // Mobile number with country code (but without + or 00)
$imei =     ""; // MAC Address for iOS IMEI for other platform (Android/etc) 


$countrycode = substr($sender, 0, 2);
$phonenumber=substr($sender, 2);

if ($argc < 2) {
    echo "USAGE: ".$_SERVER['argv'][0]." [-l] [-s <phone> <message>] [-i <phone>]\n";
    echo "\tphone: full number including country code, without '+' or '00'\n";
    echo "\t-s: send message\n";
    echo "\t-l: listen for new messages\n";
    echo "\t-i: interactive conversation with <phone>\n";
    exit(1);
}

$dst=$_SERVER['argv'][2];
$msg = "";
for ($i=3; $i<$argc; $i++) {
    $msg .= $_SERVER['argv'][$i]." ";
}

echo "[] Logging in as '$nickname' ($sender)\n";
$wa = new WhatsProt($sender, $imei, $nickname, true);

$url = "https://r.whatsapp.net/v1/exist.php?cc=".$countrycode."&in=".$phonenumber."&udid=".$wa->encryptPassword();
$content = file_get_contents($url);
if(stristr($content,'status="ok"') === false){
    echo "Wrong Password\n";
    exit(0);
}

$wa->Connect();
$wa->Login();

if ($_SERVER['argv'][1] == "-i") {
    echo "\n[] Interactive conversation with $dst:\n";
    stream_set_timeout(STDIN,1);
    while(TRUE) {
        $wa->PollMessages();
        $buff = $wa->GetMessages();
        if(!empty($buff)){
            print_r($buff);
        }
        $line = fgets_u(STDIN);
        if ($line != "") {
            if (strrchr($line, " ")) {
                // needs PHP >= 5.3.0
                $command = trim(strstr($line, ' ', TRUE));
            } else {
                $command = $line;
            }
            switch ($command) {
                case "/query":
                    $dst = trim(strstr($line, ' ', FALSE));
                    echo "[] Interactive conversation with $dst:\n";
                    break;
                case "/accountinfo":
                    echo "[] Account Info: ";
                    $wa->accountInfo();
                    break;
                case "/lastseen":
                    echo "[] Request last seen $dst: ";
                    $wa->RequestLastSeen("$dst"); 
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "[] Send message to $dst: $line\n";
                    $wa->Message(time()."-1", $dst , $line);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}

if ($_SERVER['argv'][1] == "-l") {
    echo "\n[] Listen mode:\n";
    while (TRUE) {
        $wa->PollMessages();
        $data = $wa->GetMessages();
        if(!empty($data)) print_r($data);
        sleep(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}

echo "\n[] Request last seen $dst: ";
$wa->RequestLastSeen($dst); 

echo "\n[] Send message to $dst: $msg\n";
$wa->Message(time()."-1", $dst , $msg);
echo "\n";
?>
```

To run this script, you are meant to go to the Command Line, down to the directory the file is in, and then type in something like `php -s "whatsapp.php" "Number" "Message"`.

But what if I wanted to bypass the Command Line altogether and do that directly inside the script so that I can run it at any time from my Web Server, how would I do that?

Comment: It would be better to rewrite the code so that it can be called from code directly.

Comment: Your question is really vague , what do you mean by "mimic cmd run" ? A webserver does that for you . A url is like a cmd run www.foo.bar/script.php?arg1=1&arg2=2 . The question is really strange because i see you downvoted the exec/shel_exec answeres. -1

Comment: @TudorTudor: Why would you assume I'm the one who downvoted the exec/shel_exec answer?  I rarely downvote an answer unless it's some kind of Spam, so I wasn't the one who downvoted that answer.  You, on the other hand, seem to downvote questions based on whether you think the OP has downvoted an answer, which I find quite ridiculous.  As for my question, I believe it's pretty straightforward.  What would be the equivalent in a stand-alone PHP script of running `php -s "whatsapp.php" "Number" "Message"` with the script above?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should be using [**getopt**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php).

In PHP it supports both short and long formats.

Usage demos are documented at the page I've linked to.  In your case, I suspect you'll have difficulty detecting whether a `<message>` was included as your `-s` tag's second parameter.  It will probably be easier to make the message a parameter for its own option.

```
$options = getopt("ls:m:i:");

if (isset($options["s"] && !isset($options["m"])) {
  die("-s needs -m");
}
```

As for running things from a web server ... well, you pass variables to a command line PHP script using `getopt()` and `$argv`, but you pass variables from a web server using `$_GET` and `$_POST`.  If you can figure out a sensible way to map $_GET variables your command line options, you should be  good to go.

Note that a variety of other considerations exist when taking a command line script and running it through a web server.  Permission and security go hand in hand, usually as inverse functions of each other.  That is, if you open up permissions so that it's allowed to do what it needs, you may expose or even create vulnerabilities on your server.  I don't recommend you do this unless you'll more experienced, or you don't mind if things break or get attacked by script kiddies out to 0wn your server.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for backticks, see

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Or you can use shell_exec()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php